# How to ignore/override datatemplates from parent?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datatemplate

## Situation

I have created some DataTemplates WITHOUT KEYS for my Frame , so it can understand what page it should show if i put a ViewModel from Page in his Content. That works fine . But i want to use those Datatemplates in my ItemsControl.Rescources, so Items could get differnet look.

## The Problem

If i alrdy have some Datatemplates for those ViewModels in my App.Rescources then i cant use/override them in my ItemsControl.Resources. I dont get any Compile time Errors, but after starting the Program it says the ,that the Content of Items cant be a Page.

## Example

```
<App>
   <App.Resources>

 <Datatemplate Datatype="{x:Type ViewModel1}">
    <Page1/>
 </Datatemplate>

 <Datatemplate Datatype="{x:Type ViewModel2}">
    <Page2/>
 </Datatemplate>

 </App.Resources>
 </App>

<ItemsControl>
   <ItemsControl.Resources>

 <Datatemplate Datatype="{x:Type ViewModel1}">
    <Button1/>
 </Datatemplate>

 <Datatemplate Datatype="{x:Type ViewModel2}">
    <Image1/>
 </Datatemplate>

 </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: try `DataType="{x:Type ViewModel1}"`. This solves many problems

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek thanks for your reply , this example isnt my actual code in my code i have those "x:Type"-s , i think you cant write without.

Comment: if so, I would suggest implementing TemplateSelector - haven't done that myself, but more than few times I read questions that this was the answer

Comment: No reason why this shouldn't be working, the templates in your ItemsControl resources block take precedence. Must be something else in your code not shown here.